# Creating view in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

I want to create a view on a hive table which is partitioned . My view definition is as below:

```
create view schema.V1 as select t1.* from scehma.tab1 as t1 inner join (select record_key ,max(last_update) as last_update from scehma.tab1 group by record_key) as  t2 on t1.record_key=t2.record_key and t1.last_update=t2.last_update
```

My table of tab1 is partitioned on quarter_id.

When i run any query on the view it gives error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10041]: No partition predicate found for Alias "V1:t2:tab1" Table "tab1"
```

Regards
Jayanta Layak

Answer (score 0):

Your Hive settings must be set to execute jobs in Strict mode (Default in Hive 2.x). This prevents queries of partitioned tables without a WHERE clause that filters on partitions.

If you need to run a query across all partitions(full table scan) you can set the mode to
    'nonstrict'. Use this property with care as it triggers enormous mapreduce jobs.

```
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
```

If you don't need an entire table scan, you can simply specify the partition value in your query's WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already know that. My question is how can we create views on partitioned table?